# STM32 12V input via NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, stm32, bjt, npn

I'm trying to sense a 12V input on a STM32 microcontroller.
This is the schematic I came up with:
[image]

When I short the pins of CN1 the STM pin goes LOW and I can read correctly that there is an input.

**The problem** is that if I touch with my finger CN1 the STM input goes LOW (but LED1 stays turned off): the transistor is very sensitive.

If I replace the pulldown resistor R14 with a 2.2K resistor the input does not go low when I touch it with my finger, but if I touch it with a barely wet finger it goes LOW.
Since this input starts a motor when CN1 is short circuited I would like to have a **reliable** way to read the input, which is not easily influenced in ways such as touching the connector with a wet finger. Also it is worth mentioning that some pretty long cables (up to 100m) will be connected to CN1 to remotely start the motor, so I'm worried that some kind of noise could trigger the input (and in turn the motor).

I have thought about replacing the transistor with an optocoupler but I have limited space on the board and it would be very difficult to do.

Is there a way to "desensitize" the npn transistor?

Comment: have you considered using only a voltage divider?

Answer (score 1):

That's an odd way to wire the transistor. This is far more normal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOw3p4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistor won't start to turn on until the base reaches about 0.6V and that won't happen until you get at least 9.6V at the input. Up till that point all the input current will flow through R1.

You can add some immunity to noise by adding a capacitor across R1.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE9XzN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When open on the left, \$R_1\$ pulls the I/O pin down to ground. When tied to \$+12\:\text{V}\$ there will be about \$360\:\mu\text{A}\$ into the emitter. The cascoded \$Q_1\$ will pass along that current into \$R_1\$ and try to produce a voltage drop of \$3.6\:\text{V}\$.

But because of \$D_1\$, this means \$Q_1\$'s collector would need to be over \$4.2\:\text{V}\$. That's not going to happen as the emitter voltage won't exceed \$4\:\text{V}\$. So the collector cannot be also more than, say, \$3.9\:\text{V}\$. And given \$D_1\$'s drop, this means the I/O pin will sit quite close to \$3.3\:\text{V}\$.

With about \$320-330\:\mu\text{A}\$ in \$R_1\$, the remaining \$30-40\:\mu\text{A}\$ will be in \$Q_1\$'s base. That means a saturated \$8\le \beta\le 11\$, which is just fine. So the value of \$R_2\$ is about right, I think.

Answer (score 0):

R16 is quite small for the amount of current you actually need through Q5.  Try increasing it by a factor of 10 to 50.

Comment: Removing R14 makes the impedance even higher so even higher amount of resistance at the CN1 starts to turn on the transistor.

Comment: True, I will remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

Change the relatively high R14 value to some relatively low value. 1 kohm will require 12mA, but the resistors are organized so that even 1V will start slightly turning on the transistor. Maybe move R14 as a Vbe resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using transistors I would suggest using a simple voltage divider instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK8jQK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the simplest possible solution and often times the preferred one when dealing with high-voltage sensing by low-voltage instruments. This solution is very effective and is extremely unlikely to fail while being operated under normal conditions (that is that low impedance 12V are applied to the input). The passive current draw will be less than a milliamp when input is applied, and virtually zero without an input. You can add an optional Zener diode (D1) with 3.3V Zener voltage as a precaution to be extra safe in case more than 12V are connected to the input, it will short the extra voltage on the output to ground and protect the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a mains-powered supply that has some 'leakage' (maybe current through a Y safety capacitor (well, hopefully, Y rated) to your circuit ground. That means that part of the circuit is completed through your body. It must be several hundred uA to cause the effects you mention, which is permissible in some cases.

An optocoupler could help eliminate the effects of that. Or, if your power supply is just for testing (or if you could earth the negative terminal) maybe it will go away when you use a more realistic configuration.

Here is a possible optocoupler circuit. D2 is optional but will protect against large negative transients. R3 limits the minimum current to operate the circuit. Note that there is no common ground between the two. If you ground the input circuit to your circuit ground you'll likely see little to no improvement from your present circuit.

[image]

Given the relatively slow rise time you might want to use a  Schmitt trigger input if that is available.